# Validator on UpdatePanel causes Chrome not to exit UpdateProgress

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, google-chrome

I have encountered a weird problem that does not exist in Firefox or IE.  I have a user control that has a text box and a required field validator.  When the user control is hosted in an update panel, the UpdateProgress tag never closes the first time that the UpdateProgress is triggered on the page when the page is viewed in Chrome.  Has anyone else encountered this, and if so, is there any solution other than removing the validator?  I could manually validate, but who wants to do that to support a browser bug?

Answer (score 1):

> The workaround simply tells ASP.NET AJAX that Safari 3 and Google Chrome are a new type of browser instead of the old Safari for which workarounds had to be programmed.

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/10/20/Gotcha-WebKit-(Safari-3-and-Google-Chrome)-Bug-with-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx